# You are given an array consisting of n integers. Print the last two digits of the product of its array values

Tags: python, arrays, list

#### Input

The first line of input contains an integer n, which is the number of elements in the given array.
The second line of input contains n space separated integers, which are the elements of the given array.

#### Output

Print the last two digits of the product of the array values.
Note that you always need to print two digits.

#### Constraints

```
1 <= n <= 100
1 <= arr[i] <= 100. arr[i] is the i​th​ element of the given array.
```

#### Example #1

```
Input
2
25 10
Output
50
Explanation: 25 * 10 = 250
```

Comment: Hi @mihrex, could you clarify exactly what is the question here? This looks like a copy-paste of an exercise. Please write a specific technical question related to this problem, along with what you have tried and what error or unexpected behaviour you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this (it's version of Python3):

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

result = 1
for num in arr:
    result = (result * num) % 100

print("{:02d}".format(result))
```

A little bit modify for better algorithm:

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

result = 1
for num in arr:
    result = (result * num) % 100
    if(result==0): break   # 0 multiply by any number still be 0

print("{:02d}".format(result))
```

Answer (score -2):

Java.

```
private static String display(List<Integer> ary) {
        int tempresult = 1;

        if (ary.size() == 0)
            return "0";
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < ary.size(); j++) {
                tempresult *= ary.get(j);
            }

            int result = tempresult % 100;

            if (result < 10) {
                return "0" + result;
            }

            else
                return String.valueOf(result);
        }

    }`
```

The output should of 2 characters, so if the result is 1 char needs to convert into 2 then print the result.